# Ionic 5 angular [CORS POLICY in get methode]

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I want get data from external api but i'm blocked because of cors policy , i cannot modify header at server side.

I found some solutions but not work for me,one of them is use chrome extension but when i run the application in my device i got the same error

Error Msg:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'URL' from origin 'http://localhost:8100'
> has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't
> pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
> present on the requested resource.

This is my code:

```
const url = 'http://host.com:port_number/get.php';
let headers=new HttpHeaders({
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Accept,X-Custom-Header',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials':'true'
});
return this.http.get(url, {headers:headers, params: new HttpParams().set('username', this.log).set('password', this.pass), responseType: 'text' ,observe: 'response'}).subscribe(
  data => {
    
    console.log(data);
  },
  error => console.error(error),
  () => {
  });
```

Comment: So you want to bypass CORS policy of a server that you can't control from the client?

Comment: Yes exactly, the owner wants to update his application, it is developed with Java and they don't have this error but now I want to create one with ionic and I'm stuck

Answer (score 0):

Under `resources > android > xml`  Create the file `network_security_config.xml` and add the domains you want to GET data from.

Then add `<application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />`

to your config.xml file

Comment: I try this but doesnt work for me

this is my network_security_config.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <!-- <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain> -->
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://muhost.tv:port/get.php</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>